# UI Tests Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

I am recording tests in visual studio 2012 for one of my project, it recorded the first one and after that I paused generated a method and after resuming and while generating code for this it says Coded UI Test Builder "Value cannot be null parameter name:Key"

Does anyone know whats the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue a while back. Simply closing the test builder, building the solution, then closing and reopening should fix it.

If the issue persists, then perhaps it is because of where you wish to place the UI test method. Try placing it at the top

Example (see how I commented out the previous recording, and new recording is placed on top):

```
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
        {

            this.UIMap.RecordedMethod15();



            // this.UIMap.RecordedMethod5();

            //this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();
            //this.UIMap.RecordedMethod2();
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the standard argumentnullexception message. This could be happening due to the type of control that you are recording on.

If the UI is not a custom UI could you provide the steps to repro the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and solved it by adding UIMap to the CUIT.

I notice that after I added the `Coded UI Test Project` the `Coded UI test Map` was not created, so by right clicking on the created `Coded UI Test Project` (i.e. `CodedUITestProject1`) in the `Solution Explorer` windows, then `Add` -> `New Item...` and select `Coded UI test Map` item under `Test` category, solve the problem.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but I got this error when I right clicked and selected "Add Unit Tests" to one of the methods in my controller. I solved it by building the solution, then going back and following the same steps to add the unit test.